# FastAPI: " ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python, python-3.x, swagger-ui, fastapi

I am new to FastAPI and I've been having this problem with importing my other files.

I get the error:‍‍‍‍

```py
from . import schemas
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

For context, the file I am importing from is a Folder called Blog. I saw certain StackOverflow answers saying that instead of `from . import schemas` I should write `from Blog import schemas`. And even though their solution is right and I don't get any errors while running the python program, When I try running FastAPI using uvicorn, I get this error and my localhost page doesn't load.

```
  File "./main.py", line 2, in <module>
from Blog import schemas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Blog'
```

The file structure looks like this:
[image]

The code to the main file looks like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from Blog import schemas, models
from database import engine

app = FastAPI()

models.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


@app.post('/blog')
def create(request: schemas.Blog):
    return request
```

schemas.py

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Blog(BaseModel):
    title: str
    body: str
```

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHAMY_DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite:///./blog.db'

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHAMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False})

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False)

Base = declarative_base()
```

models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from database import Base


class Blog(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'blogs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String)
    body = Column(String)
```

The SwaggerUI is not loading either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Hi Chris, I've already done all of those as mentioned above. I am still getting the same error  <b>ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Blog' </b>

Comment: @Chris I've edited my question and posted all the code along with the file structure there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your `schemas.py` and `models.py` files are in the **same directory** as your `main.py` file, you should import those two modules as follows, instead of using `from Blog import schemas, models`:

```py
import schemas, models
```

For more details and examples please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73647164/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342222/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080756/17865804).

Answer (score 15):

You can also run your app from the folder above. For example if you use uvicorn, you can do

```
uvicorn folder.main:app --reload
```

instead of

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

then you can keep the dot.

Comment: Why would he run `[...] main:app`?? The syntax of FastAPI is the same has importing in a regular Python module. "from main import app" is equal to this part " main:app ". So what you 're stating would only work if he had a module named "app" and the FastApi object is main. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/manually/

Comment: because this is the syntax for running uvicorn from the command line? not sure I understand what you mean. This is shown even in the [website you link](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/manually/#run-the-server-program)

Comment: The first part of my comment was supposed to say "why would he run `[...] app:main` ". Look at the syntax you have suggested. It is incorrect. OP has a module "main.py" which contins the variable "app". Your suggestion is proposing he has a module "app.py" with the variable "main"

Comment: oh you're right, sharp eye, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hello for me helped this way (without dot):

```
from models import User
## instead of 
# from .models import User
```