# Python ModuleNotFoundError while importing a module in conftest for Pytest framework

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fastapi

My project structure

```
mt-kart
     |
      --> src/data_kart
     |        |
     |         -->apis
     |        |
     |         -->__init__.py
     |        |  
     |         -->main.py
      --> tests
             |
              -->__init__.py
             |
              -->conftest.py
             |
              -->test_others.py
```

`conftest.py` has the following line.

`from data_kart.main import fastapi_app`

When run `pytest` from command line from project root(mt-kart). I get the following error

`ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'data_kart'`

How to make data_kart visible for `conftest.py` .

Comment: Add `__init__.py` in data_kart

Comment: @DevangSanghani I have it. Sorry i Edited the post.

Comment: Have you tried adding `src`? `from src.data_kart.main import fastapi_app`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1

Use relative imports:

```
from ..src.data_kart.main import fastapi_app
fastapi_app()
```

Please note, the above requires running `conftest.py` outside the project's directory, like this:

```
python -m mt-kart.tests.conftest
```

### Option 2

Use the below in `conftest.py` ([ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-from-parent-directory/)):

```
import sys
import os
  
# getting the name of the directory where the this file is present.
current = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
  
# Getting the parent directory name where the current directory is present.
parent = os.path.dirname(current)

# adding the parent directory to the sys.path.
sys.path.append(parent)
  
# import the module
from src.data_kart.main import fastapi_app

# call the function
fastapi_app()
```

And if it happens for a module being outside the parent directory of `tests`, then you can get the parent of the parent direcory and add that one to the `sys.path`. For example:

```
parentparent = os.path.dirname(parent)
sys.path.append(parentparent)
```

### Option 3

Same as Option 2, but shorter.

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.insert(0, str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent))

from src.data_kart.main import fastapi_app
fastapi_app()
```

### Option 4

Options 2 and 3 would work for smaller projects, where only a couple of files need to be updated with the code above. However, for larger projects, you may consider including the directory containing your package directory in [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342222/17865804) (Option 3).

Comment: It works. Somehow I had a feeling that the `src` is detected by python as part of the project structure. So i had not tried that.