# AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'append' , Pytest , FastAPI

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fastapi

**Test file code for my fastapi app.**
**Using Mas Os**

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
import json

import os 
import sys



sys.append.path(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
from main import app

client = TestClient(app)



# email already exists
def test_createAccount_existing_User():
    input_data = {"first_name":"first", "last_name":"last", "email":"user@example2.com", "password":"1234"}
    response = client.post('/account/', json.dump(input_data))
    assert response.status_code ==  400
```

Error that I am getting:

```
ERROR test_userRoute.py - AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'append'
```

When I am running pytest -v, showing error in the terminal.

Comment: perhaps you meant `sys.path.append`?

Comment: Your operating system is irrelevant. The *sys* module has no *append* attribute just as the error message indicates. What are you hoping to achieve with that line of code?

Comment: You can explore the methods on some object with [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python import error while importing main module in conftest for Pytest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71079874/python-importerror-while-import-main-module-in-conftest-for-pytest-framework)

Answer (score 2):

To append to the path variable, use the syntax:

```py
sys.path.append
```

You have these out of order.

[`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) is a list of search paths - append is just a built in method of `list`.