# Unable to import class to the file

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to import app.config and app.routers to the main.py but when I trying to start a server terminal keeps saying:

```
 ...bla bla bla
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "/Users/temirlannz/PycharmProjects/server-v1/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
   from config import settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

This is my main.py file

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from config import settings
from routers import user, auth

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    settings.CLIENT_ORIGIN,
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


app.include_router(auth.router, tags=['Auth'], prefix='/api/auth')
app.include_router(user.router, tags=['Users'], prefix='/api/users')


@app.get("/api/healthchecker")
def root():
    return {"message": "Welcome to FastAPI with MongoDB"}
```

This is my project structure

[image: 1]

Comment: Please have a look at the following answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70874739/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73647164/17865804), as well as[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342222/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080756/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question:

> I'm trying to import app.config and app.routers to the main.py

Change

```py
from config import settings
```

to

```py
from app.config import settings
```

Python imports don't work the same way as you may be used to from other programming languages. It's very much worth reading through the ["The import system"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) documentation of python, which is very long and complex so too long to summarize here.

Avoid relative imports if you want to avoid the common trap of accidentally importing the wrong thing when you move files. Explicit absolute imports will prevent those types of problems.

Comment: Now it keeps saying

 File "/Users/temirlannz/PycharmProjects/server-v1/app/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app.routers import user, auth

Comment: @Temirlan Can you publish the complete error in your original question as an update?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
from config import settings
```

to

```
from .config import settings
```

It should work :)

**Reason**:
In Python, when you use a relative import within the same package, you should use a dot (.) to indicate the relative path to the module you want to import. The dot notation is used to specify the location of the module relative to the current module.

This problem is faced by so many people. They think normal import syntax works for in-module imports.